# Nginx SSH with Oauth/password

Tags: authentication, nginx, ssh, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm looking to use nginx to do ssh authentication. I noticed that after 1.9 nginx has streams, but there isn't really any doc on either basic_auth for the stream or some sort of oauth. Basically I want nginx to require a user/password input when ssh'ing into the server but I don't want it on the server itself. I can't use PEMs. Thanks!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot use HTTP authentication on stream connections.

Comment: This was my fear. Are there any other options for stream auth besides PEM? This is new territory for me.